# ORA-01861: literal does not match format string","StackTrace":" at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, c#-4.0, oracle11g

```
SELECT PRODESCRIPTION.PDC_DESC,PRODESCRIPTION.PD_CODE 
FROM BILLDETL,BILLMAST,PRODESCRIPTION 
WHERE BILLDETL.BMC_SLNO=BILLMAST.BMC_SLNO 
  AND PRODESCRIPTION.PD_CODE=BILLDETL.PD_CODE 
  AND BILLMAST.PT_NO='" + hospitalNo + "' 
  AND BILLDETL.ORIGINAL_OUCODE='L002' 
  AND TO_DATE(BILLMAST.BMD_DATE,'DD/MM/YY')
     =TO_DATE('" + visitDate.ToShortDateString() + "','DD/MM/YY')"
```

above query works in oracle but the error occurred when connected to oracle using asp.net oledb connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that your OLEDB connection is done from a machine with a locale that does not return the date format you're expecting from the locale dependent `ToShortDateString()`.

Try replacing `visitDate.ToShortDateString()` with a fixed - non locale dependent - date format, something like;

```cs
AND TRUNC(BILLMAST.BMD_DATE, 'DAY')
   =TO_DATE('" + visitDate.ToString("dd\\/MM\\/yy") + "','DD/MM/YY')"
```

Comment: @user2119324 Did you test the above? What - if any - error message are you getting?

Comment: @user2119324 What is the type of `BILLMAST.BMD_DATE`? VARCHAR?

Comment: No,data type is DATE the value in this field like '3/4/2013 7:39:37 AM' but the parameter 'visitDate' only refer date without time

Comment: @user2119324 If `BILLMAST.BMD_DATE` is already a date, you should replace `TO_DATE(BILLMAST.BMD_DATE,'DD/MM/YY')` with simply `TRUNC(BILLMAST.BMD_DATE, 'DAY')`

Answer (score 0):

Error Message

ORA-01861: literal does not match format string

Cause of Error

You tried to enter a literal with a format string, but the length of the format string was not the same length as the literal.

[This link may help you](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora01861.php)